# create MPI_Type_Struct for fortran polymorphic derived type

Tags: struct, fortran, mpi, derived-types

I provide my tries to construct an MPI datatype with `MPI_Type_create_struct` in order to send/receive OOP Fortran types. The type looks like

```
type :: mytype
  integer             ::  id
  logical             ::  flag
  real,   allocatable ::  x(:)
  real,   allocatable ::  y(:)
 contains
  procedure, pass     ::  ctor => mytype_ctor
end type
```

an hence is an derived type, with allocatable arrays and type-bound procedures.

**How does one create an MPI datatype for this type?**

I tried two vaiants and none of them worked.

The **first variant** tries to set the typemap explicitly from the types inside the derived type `mytype`. It uses `MPI_Type_get_extent` to calculate the displacements. 
`MPI_send` and `MPI_recv` get executed at runtime without error. But on accessing the member array `x` via `write`, the runtime error `SIGSEGV` happens.

The **second variant** uses a dummy instance of `mytype` to read the starting addresses of the members of `mytype` directly. The typemap which is returned - from my perspective - is nonsense. The addresses are scattered far to wide in address space. Sending and receiving does not work at runtime. `MPI_send` results in `SIGSEGV`.

**Is there a standard way to transfer derived types with allocatable members and routines via MPI?**

I use the `mpifort` (verion 18.0.5) to compile and run with `mpirun -n 2` (version 3.1.0). The minimal example are the following module and main program.

```
module mod
use MPI
implicit none
save

  integer               ::  MPI_mytype_v1
  integer               ::  MPI_mytype_v2

  type :: mytype
    integer             ::  id
    logical             ::  flag
    real,   allocatable ::  x(:)
    real,   allocatable ::  y(:)
  contains
    procedure, pass     ::  ctor => mytype_ctor
  end type

contains

  subroutine mytype_ctor(this, nx, ny)
  implicit none
  class(mytype),  intent(inout) ::  this
  integer,      intent(in)    ::  nx, ny
    allocate(this%y(ny))
    allocate(this%x(nx))
  end subroutine

  subroutine MPI_create_mytype_v1(nx,ny)
  implicit none
  integer, intent(in) ::  nx, ny
    integer                         ::  types(4), bsize(4)
    integer(KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND)  ::  displacement(4), types_extents(4), lb(4)
    integer i, err, rank

  bsize         = [ 1,                  1,                  nx,                  ny                 ]
  types         = [ MPI_INTEGER,        MPI_LOGICAL,        MPI_REAL,            MPI_REAL           ]

  do i=1, 4
    call MPI_Type_get_extent(types(i), lb(i), types_extents(i), err)
  enddo

  do i=1, 4
    displacement(i) = sum( bsize(1:i-1)*types_extents(1:i-1) )
  enddo

  call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, err)
  if(rank==0) then
    write(*,'(a)'    ) 'creation with method 1 - layout'
    write(*,'(a,4I5)') 'size  ', bsize
    write(*,'(a,4I5)') 'type  ', types
    write(*,'(a,4I5)') 'extnt ', types_extents
    write(*,'(a,4I5)') 'displ ', displacement
  endif

  call MPI_Type_create_struct(4, bsize, displacement, types, MPI_mytype_v1, err)
  call MPI_Type_commit(MPI_mytype_v1, err);
  end subroutine


  subroutine MPI_create_mytype_v2(nx,ny)
  implicit none
  integer, intent(in) ::  nx, ny
    type(mytype)                    ::  MTdummy
    integer                         ::  types(4), bsize(4)
    integer(KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND)  ::  displacement(4), address(4)
    integer i, err, rank

    bsize         = [ 1,                  1,                  nx,                  ny                 ]
    types         = [ MPI_INTEGER,        MPI_LOGICAL,        MPI_REAL,            MPI_REAL           ]


    call mytype_ctor(MTdummy, nx,ny)
    call MPI_get_Address(MTdummy%id,   address(1), err)
    call MPI_get_Address(MTdummy%flag, address(2), err)
    call MPI_get_Address(MTdummy%x(1), address(3), err)
    call MPI_get_Address(MTdummy%y(1), address(4), err)

    do i=1, 4
      displacement(i) = MPI_Aint_diff(address(i), address(1))
    enddo

    call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, err)
    if(rank==0) then
      write(*,'(a)'     ) 'creation with method 2 - layout'
      write(*,'(a,4I5)' ) 'size    ', bsize
      write(*,'(a,4I5)' ) 'type    ', types
      write(*,'(a,4I25)') 'displ   ', displacement
      write(*,'(a,4I25)') 'adresses', address
    endif

    call MPI_Type_create_struct(4, bsize, displacement, types, MPI_mytype_v2, err)
    call MPI_Type_commit(MPI_mytype_v2, err);
  end subroutine

end module
```

```
program main
use mod
use MPI
implicit none
type(mytype)  ::  MT, MTrec
integer       ::  err, rank, n_procs

call MPI_Init(err)
call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, err)
call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, n_procs, err)

call MPI_create_mytype_v1(3,7)
call MPI_create_mytype_v2(3,7)

call mytype_ctor(MT,3,7)

if(rank==0) then
  MT%id    = 0
  MT%flag  = .true.
  MT%x(:)  = [+1,+2,+3]
  MT%y(:)  = [-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7]
endif
if(rank==1) then
  MT%id    = 1
  MT%flag  = .false.
  MT%x(:)  = [0,0,0]
  MT%y(:)  = [0,1,2,4,8,16,32]
endif

if(rank==0) call MPI_Send( MT, 1, MPI_mytype_v1, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, err)
! error on sending: if(rank==0) call MPI_Send( MT, 1, MPI_mytype_v2, 1, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, err)
if(rank==1) then
  call mytype_ctor(MTrec,3,7)
  call MPI_Recv( MTrec, 1, MPI_mytype_v1, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD,  MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, err)
  ! call MPI_Recv( MTrec, 1, MPI_mytype_v2, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD,  MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, err)
  write(*,'(a,I0)')  'received id  ', MTrec%id
  write(*,'(a,L)' )  'received flag', MTrec%flag
  write(*,'(a,L)' )  'is x alloc?  ', allocated(MTrec%x)
  write(*,'(a,G0)')  'received x   ', MTrec%x(1)
  write(*,'(a,G0)')  'received x   ', MTrec%x(2)
  write(*,'(a,G0)')  'received x   ', MTrec%x(3)
  write(*,'(a,7G0)') 'received y   ', MTrec%y
endif

call MPI_finalize(err)
end program
```

The *fixed* layout looks like a reasonable typemap.

```
creation with method 1 - layout
size      1    1    3    7
type      7    6   13   13
extnt     4    4    4    4
displ     0    4    8   20
```

The layout from MPI address lookup seems buggy.

```
creation with method 2 - layout
size        1    1    3    7
type        7    6   13   13
displ                           0                        4         -140732799234248         -140732798626120
adresses          140732823825384          140732823825388                 24591136                 25199264
```

Upon execution with the *first variant* the data type gets send and received. Writing its members (and a test for allocation of the member array `x`) produces:

```
received id  0
received flag T
is x alloc?   T
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you want - do you want a single MPI derived type handle for all instantiations of variables of type mytype? If so you will be disappointed - the MPI handle is effectively a handle for the layout of the data in memory, and as this can vary between instantiations you can't have one handle to rule them all.

Comment: In the above example the variables `x` and `y` are of course always of a constant size. I explicitly tell MPI their size at runtime. Hence the memory layout of the type in principle *can* be fixed, if the compiler supports this.

Comment: Fixed size doesn't necessarily mean fixed layout in memory if the components are allocatable - if you allocate x and y each time you instantiate such a type there is no guarantee that they will always be in the same addresses relative to each other.  In principle you will need an MPI derived type for each case.

Comment: Ok, this really sounds dissapointing. So the best workaround would be to wrap the MPI_send and MPI_receive for the type and send all its members sequentially, I guess!?

Comment: Or wrap the comms, create the type when required, and send that. I would send each member separately, but I'm old and stuck in ways.

Comment: The problem with sending the members is, that tag handling is much more complicated with a lot of members. On the other hand transfering an array of those derived types, forces me to create an MP datatype for each of them, since I cannot ensure their layout is the same. This will most likely produce some overhead...